# How to create Android APK expansion files with lot of Drawable images

Tags: java, android

I implemented application which contains so many image in drawables. It leads to increase size of the apk file. I have read the Android developers docs about APK expansion. But my case all my resources (images) are in drawable only, and i am referring these images in xml and java files.
Is it possible to convert all the drawable images into expansion file (.zip) with out making any changes in java and xml file changes.

Please share your idea is it possible or not.